# Oauth2client Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I am trying to link my python with the google sheet. But Something is going wrong and I tried reinstalling oauth2client but still no success.
Here is the code

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
```

Error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gdb.py", line 7, in <module>
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(r"C:\Users\Moham\Desktop\Amazon\ii.json", scope)
  File "C:\UsersPrograms\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 221, in from_json_keyfile_name
    return cls._from_parsed_json_keyfile(client_credentials, scopes,
  File "C:\UsersPrograms\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 169, in _from_parsed_json_keyfile
    creds_type = keyfile_dict.get('type')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Part of my creds.json (There is "type" in this json)

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "tstingdb",
....,
}
```

WHat is going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback please?

Comment: @TomDalton I thought only the last line was important. I have edited the question now

Comment: The line in your traceback `creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(r"C:\Users\Moham\Desktop\Amazon\ii.json", scope)` doesn't match the line of code you have provided (`creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)`).

Comment: Is it possible the keyfile doesn't exist or isnt readable?

Comment: Also worth saying that https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client seems to be deprecated and last commit to is was in 2018. According to the repo you might be better off looking to use the `google-auth` and `oauthlib` packages instead.

Comment: @TomDalton Dont worry about that. the file name was ```ii.json``` when I run the code. But before pasting the question I changed it to``` cred.json```.  I first thought maybe the file is not being read so that I changed the name. Also if the file is not readable it gives me the error (I tried to give a fake file name) ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\Desktop\\asdasdasdi.json'```

Comment: Based on the traceback, it looks like in here https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/service_account.py#L219-L223 the `client_credentials` variable is somehow getting set to None. I can't immediately see why or how that can happen. You'll probably need to debug the code locally to work out what's happening there.

Comment: Let me try with the ```google-auth``` and ```oauthlib```